# Google Maps API - How to move map without snapping to location?

Tags: android, google-maps, maps

I started teaching myself to work with Android Studio as a school project and want to use the Google Maps API in this app.

I have a map with my location on it but every time I move the camera it immediately recenters my camera to my position.

My current code is this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_marker_icon);
    Bitmap b = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
    Bitmap smallMarker = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, 40, 40, false);
    mo = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("My Current Location").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker));
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 && !isPermissionGranted()) {
        requestPermissions(PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
    } else requestLocation();
    if (!isLocationEnabled())
        showAlert(1);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    marker = mMap.addMarker(mo);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    LatLng myCoordinates = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    marker.setPosition(myCoordinates);
    CameraUpdate center = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(myCoordinates);
    CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15.0f);
    mMap.moveCamera(center);
    mMap.animateCamera(zoom);

}
```

Comment: The camera moves every time your location is changing, as per your code. What do you want to achieve, exactly?

Comment: What I want to achieve is that the camera moves with my location when I'm walking but once I move the camera away I don't want it to move back without pressing a button. With my limited knowledge I don't know how to do this and I couldn't find any other post that will fix my problem

Comment: You can use a swipe listener on the map, after a swipe you can disable the location listener. Then it will stop updating your location and moving the camera.You can restarted with another event (ex: a click on a button for "my location").

Comment: Thanks Mihai i'll look into that